# RUBY Nokogiri CSS HTML Parsing

Tags: html, css, ruby, parsing, nokogiri

I'm having some problems trying to get the code below to output the data in the format that I want. What I'm after is the following:

> CCC1-$5.00
>   CCC1-$10.00
>   CCC1-$15.00
>   CCC2-$7.00

where $7 belongs to CCC2 and the others to CCC1, but I can only manage to get the data in this format:

> CCC1-$5.00
>   CCC1-$10.00
>   CCC1-$15.00
>   CCC1-$7.00
>   CCC2-$5.00
>   CCC2-$10.00
>   CCC2-$15.00
>   CCC2-$7.00

Any help would be appreciated.

```
require 'rubygems'  
require 'nokogiri'  
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(<<-eohtml)
<div class="AAA">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" summary="sum">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="BBB">
                    <span class="CCC">CCC1</span>
                </td>
                <td class="DDD">
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr><td class="FFF">$5.00</td></tr>
                            <tr><td class="FFF">$10.00</td></tr>
                            <tr><td class="FFF">$15.00</td></tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" summary="sum">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="BBB">
                    <span class="CCC">CCC2</span>
                </td>
                <td class="DDD">
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                         <tbody>
                             <tr><td class="FFF">$7.00</td></tr>
                         </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
eohtml

doc.css('td.BBB > span.CCC').each do |something|
    doc.css('tr > td.EEE,  tr > td.FFF').each do |something_more|
        puts something.content + '-'+ something_more.content
    end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
doc.css('td.BBB > span.CCC').each do |something|
    something.parent.parent.css('tr > td.EEE,  tr > td.FFF').each do |something_more|
        puts something.content + '-'+ something_more.content
    end
end
```

Comment: Could you say the meaning of `'td.BBB > span.CCC'`? where is the documentation?

Comment: '>' in css syntax is explained @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459821/css-selector-what-is-it