# CSS '>' selector; what is it?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I've seen the "greater than" (`>`) used in CSS code a few times, but I can't work out what it does. What does it do?

Comment: Check these references :[https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html%23id-selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html%23id-selectors), [https://web.dev/learn/css/selectors/](https://web.dev/learn/css/selectors/)

Answer (score 809, accepted):

### `>` selects immediate children

For example, if you have nested divs like such:

```
<div class='outer'>
    <div class="middle">
        <div class="inner">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
        <div class="inner">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and you declare a css rule in your stylesheet like such:

```
.outer > div {
    ...
}
```

your rules will apply only to those divs that have a class of "middle" since those divs are direct descendants (immediate children) of elements with class "outer" (unless, of course, you declare other, more specific rules overriding these rules). See fiddle.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
.outer > div {
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
  div.outer - This is the parent.
  <div class="middle">
    div.middle - This is an immediate child of "outer". This will receive the orange border.
    <div class="inner">div.inner - This is an immediate child of "middle". This will not receive the orange border.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    div.middle - This is an immediate child of "outer". This will receive the orange border.
    <div class="inner">div.inner - This is an immediate child of "middle". This will not receive the orange border.</div>
  </div>
</div>

<p>Without Words</p>

<div class='outer'>
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="inner">...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="inner">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Side note

If you, instead, had a space  between selectors instead of `>`, your rules would apply to both of the nested divs. The space is much more commonly used and defines a "descendant selector", which means it looks for any matching element down the tree rather than just immediate children as the `>` does.

NOTE: The `>` selector is not supported by IE6. It does work in all other current browsers though, including IE7 and IE8.

If you're looking into less-well-used CSS selectors, you may also want to look at `+`, `~`, and `[attr]` selectors, all of which can be very useful.

[This page](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/) has a full list of all available selectors, along with details of their support in various browsers (its mainly IE that has problems), and good examples of their usage.

Comment: @JamWaffles - I've added more info, along with a link to Quirksmode.org which should help your research.

Comment: Neat! Thanks for the link. I already use the `[attr]` selector in a few of my projects. I'll look into `+` and `~` too.

Comment: ...and by 'current', he means every browser your visitors use... unless, of course, you don't have more than 2% of your users using IE6

Comment: @JamWaffles - if you're using `[attr]` then you're safe with `>` and '~' because browser support for those three is about the same. '+' is a bit flaky in IE7+8 but is usable.

Comment: @Spudley , The quirksmode page you linked, does not say anything about these selectors.

Comment: @Spundun - it did at the time; the quirksmode site layout has changed in the interim. The new link is http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/. I'll update the link in the answer.

Comment: I feel a user can look at this example and walk away thinking that `>` will select the very immediate child. I think the example above can be improved by showing multiple immediate children being affected.

Comment: Urge was too real. Made a bunch of edits and added in the fiddle.

Comment: So what does > do?

Comment: It is worth to notice that > looks only ONE level down the markup structure and not further deep down.

Answer (score 226):

### `>` selects all **direct descendants/children**

A space  selector will select all deep descendants whereas a greater than `>` selector will only select all immediate descendants. See fiddle for example.

```css
div { border: 1px solid black; margin-bottom: 10px; }
.a b { color: red; } /* every John is red */
.b > b { color: blue; } /* Only John 3 and John 4 are blue */
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <p><b>John 1</b></p>
  <p><b>John 2</b></p>
  <b>John 3</b>
  <b>John 4</b>
</div>

<div class="b">
  <p><b>John 1</b></p>
  <p><b>John 2</b></p>
  <b>John 3</b>
  <b>John 4</b>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 The only example showing the difference between the whitespace combinator and the `>` combinator. You may want to give `div>b` a different color to better illustrate the difference though.

Comment: @Adam Kiss: Don't worry, over time as votes accumulate I believe you'll be on your way to Populist... check back next year :D

Comment: @Adam Kiss - don't worry; you still scored more rep points than I did. (and I voted for your answer too, so no hard feelings, eh?)

Comment: +1 for to the point. demo: http://codepen.io/krish4u/pen/jpKhG

Comment: @AdamKiss `>` for whatever reason "direct descendant/child" sounds to me like the very immediate child (singular). However, `>'  refers to all direct descendants/children.

Comment: It is worth to notice that > looks only one level down the markup structure and not further deep down.

Answer (score 15):

It is the CSS child selector. Example:

`div > p` selects all paragraphs that are direct children of div.

See [this](http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200006b.html)

Answer (score 11):

As others have said, it's a direct child, but it's worth noting that this is different to just leaving a space... a space is for any descendant.

```
<div>
  <span>Some text</span>
</div>
```

`div>span` would match this, but it would *not* match this:

```
<div>
  <p><span>Some text</span></p>
</div>
```

To match that, you could do `div>p>span` or `div span`.

Answer (score 4):

It declares parent reference, look at this page for definition:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors

Comment: *sidenote:* You trust w3schools? oops. Read http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: No I do not trust w3schools, but occasionally they do get it right ;) But if you have a better link explaining parent references I would be more than happy to recommend that instead, when I wrote this I had not realized w3schools errors yet :P

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors

Answer (score 4):

It is a Child Selector.

It matches when an element is the child of some element. It is made up of two or more selectors separated by ">".

Example(s):

The following rule sets the style of all P elements that are children of BODY:

```
body > P { line-height: 1.3 }
```

Example(s):

The following example combines descendant selectors and child selectors:

```
div ol>li p
```

It matches a P element that is a descendant of an LI; the LI element must be the child of an OL element; the OL element must be a descendant of a DIV. Notice that the optional white space around the ">" combinator has been left out.

Answer (score -3):

It means parent/child

example:

html>body

that's saying that body is a child of html

Check out: [Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)