# What does ">" do in CSS

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “>” mean in CSS rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-mean-in-css-rules)

I have seen this in some CSS

> body > .navid

What I want to know is, what does the ">" sign do in this CSS piece of code?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459821/css-selector-what-is-it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's a selector for children (not just any descendent).

The selector `body > .navid` would select the `.navid` div using the following:

```
<body>
    <div class="navid"></div>
</body>
```

But it would not select the `.navid` div below because it's a grandchild

```
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="navid"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

It points to the direct child of an element so for example you can have

> body > .something

it points to the class "something" within only the body element.

Answer (score 0):

It's called the [Descendant selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators), it selects

> an F element child of an E element

Reference : http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/