# What does this css selector/syntax mean?

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “>” mean in CSS rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-mean-in-css-rules)
>   [CSS ‘>’ selector; what is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459821/css-selector-what-is-it)

What means:

```
#nav > li > ul
```

Google is ignoring the > and I dont know, what it means. I mean the ">".

Comment: You can Google `css greater than`

Comment: Did you mean `#nav > ul > li`

Comment: Read this: http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Comment: #nav (id of the element) child li and child ul
<div id="nav"><ul><li>d<ul><li>f</li></ul></li></ul></div>

Answer (score 4):

The `>` indicates that the element should be a direct child, not just a descendant.

---

Given the following piece of HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The following CSS selector would match the list item:

```css
#nav li { }
```

While this one wont:

```css
#nav > li { }
```

Answer (score 1):

`>` is a child selector. This means that it will match the immediate child and not others otherwise nested.

For example, this css: `div > p > span` will match this HTML:

```
<div>
    <p><span>...</span></p>
</div>
```

but not this HTML:

```
<div>
    <p>
        <ul>
            <li><span> ... </span></li>
        </ul>
    </p>
</div>
```

In your example, your CSS would match a structure like follows:

```
<ul id="nav">
   <li>
        <ul> <-- this one gets matched
...
```

Without seeing the rest of the CSS, I'd assume it was to style a nested sub-menu in a navigational element.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you mean `#nav > ul > li` ?

In which case it would mean "Select the `li` tag that is the child of a `ul` tag which is in itself the child of an element with the id `nav`.

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>The css selector locates this list item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```