# jquery selector confusion - $('div p') vs $('div>p')

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to learn jquery and have a question -

The div element on the page looks like -

```
<div id ="1">
    <p id="first"> one 
        <p id="second"> one.one 
            <p id="third"> one.one.one </p>
        </p>
    </p>
</div>
```

Both the below selectors are giving me the same result -

```
  $('div p').css({'background-color' : 'blue'}); 

  $('div>p').css({'background-color' : 'blue'});
```

Shouldn't the second selector just return only the first `<p>` tag of the `<div>` element ?

Comment: This isn't really jquery question but a css selector question.  Here is some more info on them:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Getting_Started/Selectors

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS '>' selector; what is it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459821/css-selector-what-is-it)

Comment: just a heads up, the "proper" way to do it (from a speed / efficiency standpoint) is `$('div').find('p')`. This will always be faster than the CSS selector method. http://jsperf.com/jquery-find-vs-css-selector2/2

Comment: `<p>` tags' closing tag is optional.  Your code is being parsed as `<div><p>one</p><p>one.one</p>...`.  Docs: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html#p-tags

Comment: @LifeInTheGrey I wonder how selecting by tagname compares to selecting by ID?( my guess would be that by ID would be much faster, thus making the jsperf linked somewhat off-topic )

Comment: @KevinB well the tagname is the child, and it would be moronic to specify a parent when you use an ID to select the child. so ...

Comment: @FelixKling: They are not actually descendants.  They are being read as siblings since the closing `</p>` is optional.

Comment: @LifeInTheGrey: You cannot make this conclusion based on the test you linked to, since the setup and the selector is different. Here is a more appropriate test case: http://jsperf.com/jquery-find-vs-css and it's not surprising that *not* using `.find` is faster.

Comment: @Rocket: Right... I was thinking about that `p` elements cannot be nested and that the browser should correct it but I didn't bother testing... will delete my comment and thanks (and +1).

Comment: @FelixKling good find, i just grabbed the first one i could.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$('div p')` selects *all* `<p>` tags that are descendants of a `<div>`.

`$('div>p')` *only* selects `<p>` tags that are direct children of a `<div>`.

---

What's happening in your code is since the closing `</p>` tag is optional, the browser is reading your HTML as having 3 `<p>` (actually 5, since the last 2 closing tags are being "mis-read") tags that are all siblings.

So, it's being read as:

```
<div id ="1">
    <p id="first"> one</p> 
    <p id="second"> one.one</p>
    <p id="third"> one.one.one</p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

That's why they all became blue.  `$('div>p')` matched them all, since they are all direct children of the `<div>` (or that's what the browser thinks).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wP7uD/

<sub>Open your browser's dev tools and inspect the DOM, you'll see that there are 5 `<p>` tags.</sub>

Moral of this: You cannot have `<p>` tags as children of `<p>` tags.

---

W3C spec for `<p>` tags: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html

Comment: +1 Because everyone else is explaining what `>` does (which the OP seems to understand already) and not why they get that result.

Comment: @FelixKling: In the OP's question he says that he expects `$('div>p')` to only return the 1st element.  He would be right if it weren't for the fact that `<p>` tags are weird.  Also, that's usually how I answer; explain *why* the OP is getting the result he is. :-D

Answer (score 2):

```
div p
```

Match all the `p` elements which are **inside a `div`**, no matter how deep they are inside.

```
div > p
```

Match all the `p` elements which are **direct child of a `div`**

What's wrong in your case is the HTML.
It's not allowed to have a `p` nested inside another `p`; browsers close the first `p` automatically, before rendering the new one.

Answer (score 2):

All the `<p>` are children of the first `<p>` element.

Comment: Unfortunately, they aren't.  `</p>`s are optional, so his code is read as `<div><p>one</p><p>one.one</p>...`.  `<p>` tags can't be children of `<p>` tags.  http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html#p-tags

Comment: @RocketHazmat Invalid? Yes. What the OP cited? Yes.

Answer (score 2):

`div > p` implies the first level `p` child of `div`. and `div p` implies `p` child of `div` anywhere in the descendant of `div`

More [documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

Answer (score 2):

- `$("div>p")` is called as **[Child Selector (“parent > child”)](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)**

  > Selects all direct child elements specified by "child" of elements specified by "parent".
- `$("div p")` is called as **[Descendant Selector (“ancestor descendant”)](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)**

  > Selects all elements that are descendants of a given ancestor.

Comment: I seems that the OP understands the difference but doesn't understand why he gets the result he gets.