# Make an item in list align to right using CSS 3

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a list as follows:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Work</a>
      <ul>
           <li><a href="#">CSS Development</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Graphic Design</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Development Tools</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Feedback</a></li>
</ul>
```

I am attaching an image of so far what I have done.

[image: .]

In this menu, I want to align feedback to the right side.
How can I do it?

Comment: I have taken this sample from this site : http://www.red-team-design.com/css3-dropdown-menu

Comment: Just added feedback option to this sample. I want it to be aligned to right side

Comment: What if you add `float: right` to the `<li>` that contains Feedback?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Add this to your CSS content.

`li:last-child` will select the last `li` of the menu list.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YpVvb/)

```
#menu > li:last-child
{
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: Thanks...! This worked perfectly... i tried it by writing #menu:last-child{ float : right; } , but this didn't work... can u tell whats the difference between two styles?

Comment: ` #menu:last-child` will try to selct the last item with the id #menu, so it doesn't select `last li` as you wanted.

Comment: This method `>` doesn't work with all browsers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459821/css-selector-what-is-it

Comment: Only for IE7 below if is not supported.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Child_selectors

Comment: @user2091061 I woulod suggest you not to use inline-style instead you should go with css class only...

Answer (score 10):

Just use `float: right;`:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Work</a>
      <ul>
           <li><a href="#">CSS Development</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Graphic Design</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Development Tools</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  <li style="float: right;"><a href="#">Feedback</a></li>
</ul>
```

You can check the **[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/mgechev/xCvuu/)**.

Answer (score 6):

Aside from `float` you can also use `position:absolute` inside of a `position:relative` container. (Inline CSS for example purposes only.)

```
<ul id="menu" style="position:relative;width:1008px;height:40px;display:block;">
 <li class="right" style="position:absolute;right:20px;">
    <a href="#">Feedback</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question but for the whole list.

Float does not realy work there, so here is what worked for me:

```css
ul{
  direction:rtl;
}
```

This way all your li elements including their ::marker's will be pulled to the right of the parent container.

You can also combine this with selectors to just move single li elements.

```css
ul:first-child,
ul:nth-child(2),
ul:last-child{
  direction:rtl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will pull the entire menu to the right and have the dropdown sub menu pull right also instead of displaying off the screen.

```
 <div class="top-menu">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right"><li class="dropdown dropdown-user">
         <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-close-others="true">
          <i class="icon-settings"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
        </a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
          <li>
            <a href="page_user_profile_1.html">
              <i class="icon-user"></i> My Profile
            </a>
         </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```