# Why does the nth-child selector select these elements?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this code:

```
<html> 
    <head>
        <style type="text/css"> 
            * > ul li:nth-child(4n+3) { color: red; }
        </style> 
    </head>
    <body> 
        <ul>
            <li id="A" class="u">1</li> 
            <li>
                <ol> 
                    <li id="B" class="u">2.1</li>
                    <li id="C" class="g">2.2</li> 
                    <li id="D" class="u">2.3</li>
                    <li id="E" class="g">2.4</li> 
                </ol>
            </li> 
            <li id="F" class="u">3</li>
        </ul> 
    </body>
</html>
```

In this it selects `2.3` and `3` but I don't understand how this happens.

My thought is: It selects simultaneously two elements in odd position relative to the parent element. But is `2.3` really the 3rd position or 7? I am really stuck, please help.

[JSFiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Kbxky/)

Comment: Ignoring the redundant `* >`, your selector means: "select every `li` that's the `4n+3`th child of its parent element, and is the descendant of a `ul` element". There's no such thing as "the" parent element with the nth-child selector. Each element on the page is checked to see if it's the nth-child relative to *its* parent element.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
* > ul li:nth-child(4n+3)
```

Firstly, the `* >` at the start of this selector is entirely redundant (It tells the browser to look for a `ul` that is a child of something else; anything else. Which of course all `ul` elements are; if nothing else, they'll be inside the `body` tag).

So you can remove that. It'll make it simpler to work with and easier to explain.

Now we're left with this:

```
ul li:nth-child(4n+3)
```

The reason it's picking both `2.3` and `3` is because both your sets of `li` elements are descended from the single parent `ul` element. Using a space between selectors tells the browser to look for *any descendants* that match; it doesn't care about how far down the tree to look for matching `li` elements, so it finds both sets.

To answer your question about why `2.3` isn't seen as the seventh element in the set, the answer is that CSS sees each set of `li` elements as an entirely separate group; even if the selector happens to match two or more sets of elements as your original selector did, it will still run a separate counter for each, so `2.3` and `3` are both seen as the third element in their respective sets.

If you want to only select elements that are *children* of the `ul` (ie *immediately* below it in the heirarchy), you need to use the child selector (`>`) rather than just a space.

```
ul > li:nth-child(4n+3)
```

This will now only select the outer set of `li` elements, so only your `3` element will be picked up.

Hope that helps explain things.

By the way, on a more general note, you might find this useful: [CSS '>' selector; what is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459821/css-selector-what-is-it/4459872#4459872)

Answer (score 1):

Item 2.3 is position 3 (n=0, 4n+3 = 3) in the innermost `ol` list. It's also selected because `ul li`  part of the selectors means "*all* `li` elements inside any `ul` element, *regardless of the nesting level*". And the `nth-child` part adds one more condition: "those of them that are 3rd, 7th, 11th and so on child of *their immediate parent*".

Answer (score 0):

It's done relative to the parent:

`#B` = index 0

`#C` = index 1

`#D` = index 2

`#E` = index 3

-

`4n` means 4 multiplied by the item's index

`+ 3` is, of course, plus 3 - meaning:

-

`#B` = index 0 = 4x0 = 0 + 3 = `3` (3rd element - index 2)

`#C` = index 1 = 4x1 = 4 + 3 = `7` (7th element - index 6)

`#D` = index 2 = 4x2 = 8 + 3 = `11` (11th element - index 10)

`#E` = index 3 = 4x3 = 12 + 3 = `15` (15th element - index 14)

Comment: "4n means 4 multiplied by the item's index" Not sure about this part. It means every 4th element.

Comment: @Anar same thing, but my explanation is easier to visualise and calculate with (personally)

Comment: It actually is, never thought it that way. Thank you for a different perspective.