# what is the difference in calling method of css?

Tags: css

Please tell me the difference between following two methods of css

method 1:

```
.class1 .class2
```

method 2:

```
.class1 > .class2
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-the-greater-than-sign-css-selector-mean possible duplicate

Comment: The more than sign is a [child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459821/css-selector-what-is-it

Answer (score 3):

The first one will apply styles to any element with the class `class2` when under, hierarchically, an element of `class1`.

The second will do the same but *only* when the element with `class2` is directly under, as in the very next hierarchical level (a child and no further descendents), an element of `class1`.

Comment: People, let's close dupes.

Answer (score 1):

First select all .class2 which are descendants of .class1
Second select all .class2 which are direct children of class1

```
<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2>
    This will be selected by both 
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="class2">
    This one only by first
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```