# Please help me to understand the following CSS code

Tags: html, css

I'm no CSS guru, by any means. Typically, I'm able to meander my way through to understand what I'm looking at and then be able to mold it into what I want.

With that said, the following CSS lines have me scratching my head and I can't find anything to help me clarify it.

```
#testmenu li:hover > a{
    color: #fafafa;
}
```

I understand the reference to the hover of an li within the testmenu ID, but the "> a" has me lost. What is going on here?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459821/css-selector-what-is-it

Comment: Thanks. I try to avoid duplicates, but I missed this one. Many thanke

Comment: Select `a` which is a direct descendant to `li` on hover of `li` which is further nested under any element having an `id` of `#testmenu`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `>` means the `a` element is a direct child of the `li`.  The MDN documentation provides a good description of this [selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors).

Here is some HTML that demonstrates the selector:

```
<ul id="testmenu">
    <li><a href="#">Will be selected</a></li>
    <li><div><a href="#">Will not be selected</a></div></li>
</ul>
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/7ePEr/

Comment: "direct" is superfluous, a DOM doesn't have any kind of children which aren't direct.

Comment: @Quentin by `direct` I'm referring to non-grand children of an element.  The MDN documentation seems to echo this verbiage, `The > combinator separates two selectors and matches only those elements matched by the second selector that are direct children of elements matched by the first.` Although not necessary, I think direct helps emphasize the point.

Answer (score 3):

`>` is the child combinator. It requires that the element matched by the right hand side be a child of the element matched by the left hand side.

See also [the Selectors specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/).

Answer (score 1):

`li:hover > a` references an `a` element that is an immediate child of `li`

<kbd>**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xckxL/)**</kbd> <kbd>**[W3C Documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/)**</kbd>

```
<ul id="testmenu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">I will change color on hover</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <a href="#">I will not</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Find id=testmenu. Get all descendants. Filter the descendants by the ones are `<li>`s and are being hovered over. Get all children. Filter children by the ones that are `<a>`s.

Answer (score 0):

The selector is selecting an `a` element that is a direct child (not many levels down, a direct descendant) of an `li` that is being hovered over that is a descendant of an element with id `testmenu`