# styling link using css in this particular html structure

Tags: css

HOw to style link with class `selected` under this html structure

```
<li class="submenu_items" style="display: list-item;">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a class="selected" href="/page">Page</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

Comment: Generally, you can use this: `.submenu_items > ul > li > a.selected`

Comment: Why everyone using `CSS Specificity` concept here; Even `.class` is already defined here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
.submenu_items ul li a.selected{
     /* your CSS properties here */
}
```

You can also use the `>` operator to [denote a direct descendant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459821/css-selector-what-is-it).

There are a number of variations in how you can target the `.selected` link, I'd also reccommend you have a look at the [MDN article on CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Answer (score 1):

Use the below to style `selected`

```
.submenu_items ul li > a.selected{/* your code goes here. */}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

To over-ride parent styles (in this case 'submenu_items') you just need to make your CSS targeting more **specific**. For example:

```
.submenu_items ul li a.selected{
/* Add your CSS */
}
```