# Style methodology (CSS)

Tags: css

I notice a few different ways of applying styles and am trying to understand the differences between them, also if one can be used interchangeably with another? IF so, which is a better approach, and is there a newer standard among the below?

```
.rootClass { /*Styles for rootClass */ }

.rootClass > a > .classA.someClass, .rootClass > a > .classB.someClassB {
   /* Styles */
}

.rootClass a.classA.someClass, .rootClass a.classB.someClassB{ 
     /* Styles */
}
```

Also it will help to understand difference between:

```
   .rootClass .classA.someClass, .rootClass .classB.someClassB{ 
         /* Styles */
    }

   .rootClass.classA.someClass, .rootClass.classB.someClassB{ 
         /* Styles */
    }
```

Assuming I have the following HTML which styles can be possibly applied among the above?

HTML1:

```
<div class="rootClass">
<a class="classA someClass">Test</a> 
</div>
```

HTML2:

```
<div class="rootClass">
     <p class="classA">Some text here</p>    
        <span>
            <p class="classA">More text here</p> 
        </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question they both mean different things? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459821/css-selector-what-is-it

Comment: They both mean different things depending on your markup, for example, in the 1st example, your markup *might* look like this:   `<div class="rootClass"><a href="#"><span class="classA someClass"></span></a></div>`  and in the 2nd example, your markup might look like this: `<div class="rootClass"><a href="#" class="classA someClass"></a></div>`

Comment: @NickR The selectors are literally meaning different things, although depending on your markup they might apply exactly the same. The selectors are not a different way of achieving the same thing, they are just different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's many ways to apply styles using specificity. These just happen to be 3 different ways. There is no 'better' way. They all have their own uses. Note that all 3 examples are applying styles to *different* objects. These aren't 3 interchangeable ways to apply the same styles to the same object.

> .rootClass { /*Styles for rootClass */ }

The above applies a style to any element with that class. Example: `<div class="rootClass">`

```
.rootClass > a > .classA.someClass, .rootClass > a > .classB.someClassB {
   /* Styles */
}
```

The above applies styles with much more specificity. It will only apply to an object with two classes that is a direct descendent of an `a` that is a direct descendent of an object with a particular class. This is much more specific than the previous example. Example: `<div class="rootClass"><a><div class="classA someClass">`

```
.rootClass a.classA.someClass, .rootClass a.classB.someClassB{ 
     /* Styles */
}
```

The above is applying styles to anchor tags that are children of a root class that also happen to have two specific classes. Example: `<div class="rootClass"><div><div><a class="classA someClass">`

Comment: downvoters? Explanation?

Comment: I thought it was a pretty good explanation.  You might want to add note to OP original question that these are not different notation styles, but rather different actual rules.

Comment: @MikeBrant yep. Good point. Also added example markup.

Comment: @DA. thanks for the edit I miss read your layout

Comment: Probably the explanations should be -above- the code, maybe that caused some confusion hence the downvotes. +1 from me.

Comment: @KaloyanIvanov I agree thatt could be confusing as typically that is the way it is done.  I made slight edit to hopefully add clarity.