# Reset the style of a HTML element

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage with elements, styles (imported and inline)

I want to reset the style for a specific element.

Example:

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    This is the parent div, it colors the <strong>strong in red</strong>
    makes a <small>small underlined</small>
    <h4>sets a margin-left 10px for a H4</h4>
    and many other stuff<br><br>
    <div class="child">
        this is the child element<br>
        here a <strong>strong should not be red</strong><br>
        <small>small should not be underlined</small>
        <h4>H4 should not have a margin-left</h4>        
        and so on...
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent strong{
    color:red;
}
.parent small{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.parent h4{
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

I want the **child** div to ignore the styles coming from his parents, including the **html** element

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/WRDft/1/) is an illustration of my example

- The styles I gave here are just examples, there are much more
- I cannot modify the parent CSS, is being dynamically generated
- My **child** div is injected in the page, I can also inject any CSS I want
- I cannot know in advance the content of the parent CSS

The only solution I found so far is including the **child** element in an Iframe, but is really really ugly!!

Any one can help how to achieve this? A JS solution is also acceptable.

Comment: Why not set styles for the child division?

Comment: You can't reset to defaults automatically the inherit styles from the parent. You have to overwrite them manually unfortunetely

Comment: Either you have to follow http://jsfiddle.net/WRDft/2/ or by using jquery/Javascript you can reset the css. You want solution in Javascript/Jquery ?

Comment: #jayesh-goyani **I cannot modify the parent CSS, is being dynamically generated** Yes, a Javascript/JQuery solution would be very good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your thoughts guys, unfortunately, the best way I managed to achieve this is by wrapping my content inside an IFrame

- Advantage: Immediate and easy reset
- Disadvantage: I cannot manipulate the elements outside of the IFrame

Answer (score 0):

```
.child strong{
    color:pink !important;
}
```

1.You adjust the injecting code css via `!important`.

2.Even though you can't predict the css of the parents you can only have some basic CSS thing for your injected code.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/WRDft/9/)

Comment: `!important` is unnecessary, usually bad practice and can be avoided here. `.child strong` will override `.parent strong` anyway if it's included afterwards.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly ya i know it but as of the question concern i am not aware of when new code is being injected.

Comment: this is for the color, what if .parent strong has a font-size, a border, a margin... Should override all possible css properties???

Comment: @skafandri since you are injecting something inside an already existing code there is no other go for you except to override the CSS old properties.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible, the parent CSS file is few thousands of lines -_-, and even if I manage to override all, it might change anytime!

Comment: @skafandri y you worry about the parent css if you can control all the possible css property of your injected content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css immediate child selector '>'

in your example

```
.parent>h4{
    margin-left: 10px;
} 


.parent>strong{
    color:red;
}
```

check the updated demo

http://jsfiddle.net/WRDft/11/

Refer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ie/aa358819(v=vs.85).aspx

[CSS '>' selector; what is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459821/css-selector-what-is-it)

Comment: I cannot use css immediate child selector!

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly and if you know what content is being injected into your child div then the JQuery solution is very simple:

```
$(".child strong").css({"color":"black"});
$(".child small").css({"text-decoration":"none"});
$(".child h4").css({"margin-left":"0"});
```

The JQuery code can then be wrapped in any sort of function you desire.

Here is your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brewersomething/WRDft/13/) with the JQuery added. Hope that helps.

Note: the JQuery [selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) - for example: `$(".child strong")` -  can be as specific or as general as you like and you can add as many css rules as you like by using a comma separated list like this:

```
$(".child strong").css({"color":"black", "font-weight":"bold", "text-decoration":"underline", etc, etc});
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been asked and discussed.

There is no way to blanket clear styles but there are work arounds.

[Reset/remove CSS styles for element only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901030/reset-remove-css-styles-for-element-only)

Comment: I tried that solution, but it freezed my browser (tried on FF and Chrome) because I had to add '*' selector since my element has many other nested elements inside