# What is the benefit of using the '>' selector in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

These two Selectors:

```
.class>li>a{}
```

and

```
.class li a{}
```

are doing exactly same job for me so can some one please tell me what is the benefit of using `>` ?

Thanks

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459821/css-selector-what-is-it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It makes the selector more specific.

The first selector only targets an anchor tag that is a child tag of a lst item that is a child tag of a CLASS.

```
<div class="fo">
<li>
<a>
```

the second select will target all anchor tags that are a descendant of a list item which is a descendant of a specific class.

```
<div class="fo">
.....
<li>
.....
<a>
```

where .... can be any other dom element

Comment: Note that in CSS Selectors the terms of [`specific` / `specificity`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) have a special meaning. Technically, a child combinator `>` itself won't change the specificity value of a selector.

Comment: Besides, `<li>` stands for *list* item, not line item.

Comment: @HashemQolami good comments, I have edited the response to reflect LI better

Answer (score 1):

With the selector > you focus on the immediate chidlrens

```
<div class="class">
  <ul>
     <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

With this part of code, the selector .class>li>a{} won't work cause the child of .class is "ul". But .class li a{} will work cause it check all in the selector tree.

```
  <ul class="class">
     <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Will work with your .class>li>a{} cause they are all immediate children.

Another exemple, if you have this html code

```
<div id="section">
  <span>some text</span>
  <div class="subSection">
    <span>some text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The selector #section>span will apply to the first span only.
The selector #section span will apply to all spans in the id section.