# What does the css selectors ~, +, > do?

Tags: css

What do the CSS selectors ~, +, and > do?

I have seen these selectors many times, but it is not clear what the main difference between them is. Can someone explain the difference between these symbols? When we should use these symbols?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the "+" (plus sign) CSS selector mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139763/what-does-the-plus-sign-css-selector-mean), [CSS '>' selector; what is it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459821/css-selector-what-is-it?rq=1)

Answer (score 9):

Those are called *combinators*, discussed [in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/).

`~` is the [general sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators). `a ~ b` selects `b` elements that are preceded (not necessarily immediately) by an `a` element.

`+` is the [adjacent sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators). `a + b` selects `b` elements **immediately** preceded by an `a` element.

`>` is the [child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators). `a > b` selects `b` elements that are *immediate children* of an `a` element.

Answer (score 0):

you can read this article which is having full information about css3 selector that you are searching for : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/703826/CSS-Selector

article also having demo link where you can go and check what this selector is doing

```
HtmlElement ~ HtmlElemnt - Select all the html element which are precedes html element.
CSS

div ~ p
{
  font:15px arial,sans-serif;
  color:red;
}
Use

<div >
<p>My name is Pranay Rana.</p>
    <span>
        <p> data </p>
  </span> 
</div>
<p>I am working as Soft Engg.</p>
<p>My Demo Page.</p>
```

in this example p element which is precedes div get highlighted with read color, in this example "I am working as Soft Engg." and "My Demo Page." text get highlighted.

---

```
HtmlElement > HtmlElemnt - Select all the html element which are child of html element. 
CSS

div > p
{
  font:15px arial,sans-serif;
  color:red;
}
Use

<div >
<p>My name is Pranay Rana.</p>
<Span>
 <p> data </p>
</Span>
</div>
<p>I am working as Soft Engg.</p>
```

in this example all p element which are child of div get highlighted with read color, but p element which are not child of div doesnt get affected.

---

```
HtmlElement + HtmlElemnt - Select all the html element which are immediate after html element. 
CSS

div + p
{
  font:15px arial,sans-serif;
  color:red;
}
Use

<div >
<p>My name is Pranay Rana.</p>
</div>
<p>I am working as Soft Engg.</p>
<p> data </p>
```

in this example p element which is immediate after div get highlighted with read color, in this example "I am working as Soft Engg." this text get highlighted.