# JavafX set tabpane colour with css

Tags: java, javafx

Two problems:

1. I'm trying to set my table backgrounds, which I've achieved. However, if I specify a default table width, the unused part of the table defaults to the javafx table appearance. How can I set this with CSS?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_YEgxccklmHSC1BcTdULWJUUFk/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_YEgxccklmHZ0d2VDFZYUVDc1E/view?usp=sharing

2. My other problem, I can't set the background behind my tabpanes to white. I cannot find the syntax for this. See below.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_YEgxccklmHZ1RFNHNlY1pYTGc/view?usp=sharing

Any help appreciated.

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding 2.) Try setting the background color of `tab-header-background`. Here an example:

```
.tab-pane>*.tab-header-area>*.tab-header-background {
   -fx-background-color: -fx-outer-border, -fx-text-box-border, white;
}
```

[image]

I copied this snippet from the default *Modena* theme and modified it.
The ['>' selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459821/css-selector-what-is-it) selects direct children and the '*' is called the [universal selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors) and it selects a single element of any type. However, it can be ommitted here, since it is used in combination with a simple selector.

Sorry I do not know how to solve your first problem yet. Maybe I'll find something.

Comment: Nice. That worked. Can you explain your syntax, the ">*", and fact that your -fx-outer-border is comma separated from the -fx-background-color? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean, why there are more than one color (`-fx-outer-border, -fx-text-box-border, white` each comma separated) ?

Comment: Thanks for your help. For anyone else that reads this, I found the caspian.css (the default FX stylesheet), and have solved most of my problems, except the one where tables columns are below their fill size, as per my examples.)