# How to left align textareas within different divs?

Tags: html, css

I want to left align the textareas within two different divs.

Below is what have tried, but it doesn't work.

```css
.credentials {
  margin-top: -5px;
  background-color: black;
}
label {
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: white;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
textarea {
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 25px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
.username {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="credentials">
  <div class="username">
    <label>Username:</label>
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="key">
    <label>Activation key:</label>
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

It outputs the following result:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this CSS table layout (no markup changes). Set the container `div` as `table`, and two inner `div`s as `table-row`, and `label` + `textarea` as `table-cell`, with some other CSS adjustments, see the comments in the code snippet.

```css
.credentials {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 10px; /*for spacing*/
}
.username, .key {
  display: table-row;
}
label, textarea {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle; /*or top/bottom*/
}
label {
  width: 1%; /*small value*/
  white-space: nowrap; /*prevent wrapping*/
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="credentials">
  <div class="username">
    <label>Username:</label>
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="key">
    <label>Activation key:</label>
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** as one of the comment below pointed out using `<input>` elements rather than `<textarea>`, and I think that makes sense. See the updated code snippet.

```css
.credentials {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 10px; /*for spacing*/
}
.credentials .username,
.credentials .key {
  display: table-row;
}
.credentials label,
.credentials input[type="text"],
.credentials input[type="password"]{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 4px;
}
.credentials label {
  width: 1%; /*small value*/
  white-space: nowrap; /*prevent wrapping*/
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="credentials">
  <div class="username">
    <label>Username:</label>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="key">
    <label>Activation key:</label>
    <input type="password">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Eutherpy don't use `<textarea>` for inputs like username/password `<textarea>` is for comments/etc

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one way to achieve this, answer of Pangloss is nice but i like to suggest something different also without touching the code.

*I would never use textarea for this kind of work*

*calc is a relative new thing check your search engine for more information*

If you don't know the  `<` selector in css i suggest to look [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459821/css-selector-what-is-it)

```css
.credentials {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  /*fallback color if nothing is found*/
}
.credentials > div > label {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 150px;
  /*maximum width of label*/
  text-align: right;
  /*style*/
  padding: 5px;
  /*style*/
}
/*extra to make sure it never flip under label and stay inside view*/

.credentials > div > textarea {
  max-width: calc(100% - (150px + 5px + 5px + 8px + 8px + 1px + 1px));
  /* min-width + padding-left + padding-right + margin-left + margin-right + border-left + border right OR just 178px */
}
```

```html
<div class="credentials">
  <div class="username">
    <label>Username:</label>
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="key">
    <label>Activation key:</label>
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```