# CSS Selector, not understanding, a inside li inside nav, Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I was making a navigation for my website, and I could not figure this out.
I think it is the easiest to give you the part of the code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid"
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="navbar-collapsed-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu fix-inverse-dropdown fix-dropdown-height"> <!-- Dropdown Items -->
              <li><a href="#">Drop1</a></li>
              <!-- <li role="seperator" class="divider"></li> -->
              <li><a href="#">Drop2</a></li>
              <!-- <li role="seperator" class="divider"></li> -->
              <li><a href="#">Drop3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li> <!-- ./dropdown -->

        </ul> <!-- ./navbar-collapse -->
      </div> <!-- ./navbar -->
    </div> <!-- ./container-fluid -->
  </nav> <!-- ./nav -->
```

I'm using bootstrap btw.
I wanted to change the color of the whole li on hover, so I tried this

```
.fix-inverse-dropdown > li:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000 !important;
}
```

In a lot of ways, then I found this.

```
.fix-inverse-dropdown > li:hover > a {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

How does this work? Why is the " > a" at the end?
And also, if I hover on the text in the a tag, will that be recognised as hovering on the li piece?

So, then I didn't want the seperators to light up on hover, and I wanted the li's to be bigger, so I tried this and removed the seperators

```
.fix-inverse-dropdown > li {
  vertical-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

But the padding's color didn't change when I was hovering on the li. 
Found this online also

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li > a {
  padding: 8px 15px;
  color: #999;
}
```

I have no idea why and how this works.
Can somebody please explain it to me? :P

I literally spent like 2 hours on this, so a big thanks to the person who helps me out

EDIT:

I kind of get it now, so what I still don't understand is this

First question: 
If I have 3 divs placed in each other, like this:

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="b'>
        <div class="c">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I change the text color in div b and c?
Why would

```
.b { color: #fff }
```

not work? Div c is inside div b, right?

Second question: 
I have a list item, li, with class biggerli. (Thanks Behran Kankul!)
In that list item is an a, without a class.
Is it possible to change the background color of the a by using the class biggerli?
Bootstrap changes the color when hovering on it by default, but I'm changing that, 
do I have to remove it seperately for the a?

I have done this now

```
.biggerli:hover,
.biggerli:hover > a {
  background-color: blue !important;
  color: white;
}
```

Can this be done shorter?

Comment: The format of your question(s) makes this a bit difficult to answer. The short answer is `li:hover > a` changes the color of `a` because `a` had a color and was not just inheriting `li`'s color, so modifying the `li:hover` color has no effect, but `li:hover > a` does.

Comment: If I color the a, wont the text only be colored?
I also added a padding to the li, so that wouldn't be colored too, right?

Comment: Please, if you have a question about padding, make a question about padding with an example to demonstrate your exact problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's a question about how those selectors work, and why mine don't work.
I didn't know the code made the a change color and not the li..

Comment: I edited my question to what I don't understand yet

Answer (score 0):

there is node hiearchy on html. > operator means immediate children.

```
<div class='a'>
    <div>
        <div>...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and you have a selector

```
.a > div { ... }
```

then it will affect the second level div, and not the third.

check it out [CSS '>' selector; what is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459821/css-selector-what-is-it)

Comment: But if I have this:
    'code' <div>
        <div>
            <div class="div1">...</siv>
        </div>
    </div> 'code'

This should work: 
    .div1 {
        font-size: 100px;
    }
Right?

Comment: Sorry it looks messed up
If the third level div had the class "div1", I could use .div1 to style that, right?
Because that didn't work too
(I tried to color the li itself)

Comment: why dont you add another class to it?  you can use !important for it.
.biggerLi { padding:5px!important}

Comment: If I do that, the padding part does not change when I hover on the li.