# Equivalent distance between elements of a menu css

Tags: html, css

I have done a menu but I can't understand why there is no equivalent distance between the elements, if you can see in the image some of the element are okay but some are not.
This is the menu:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOyiL.png)

And the code I worked on:

HTML:

```
<body style="background:#F0F0F0">
   <div class="nav" >
     <ul>
        <li><element>&#9917 </element> </li>
        <li><a href="#" id="navItem"> Home </a></li> 
        <li><a href="#" id="navItem"> Mail </a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="navItem"> Team </a></li>  
        <li><a href="#" id="navItem"> Matches </a></li> 
        <li><a href="#" id="navItem"> Club </a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="navItem"> Multimedia </a></li> 
        <li><a href="#" id="navItem"> Fans </a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="navItem"> Shop </a><li>
        <li><a href="#" id="navItem"> More </a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Messenger</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Games</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>            
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
  .nav{
        background-color:#660099;
        color:white; 
        height:20px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        text-align: center;
      }
    .nav ul {
        list-style: none;
        text-align: center;
        padding:0;

     }

    .nav a {
        display: block;
     }
    .nav li li{
        width: 70px;
        height: 30px;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 15px;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        padding-left: 0;
        text-align: left;
        margin-left: 10px;
        }

    .nav li {
        width: 70px;
        height: 50px;
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 1px;
        text-align: center;

     }
     .nav li ul {
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        width: inherit;
     }

     .nav li:hover ul {
        display: block;
     }
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: you have to work with flexbox

Comment: ID's must be unique...use a class instead of an ID for the `'navItem`.

Comment: watch out in the "HTML" you use "ID" and in the "CSS" you use "CLASS"

Comment: Can you explain me please where did I use "ID" in html. The nav has class property and the same in css

Comment: id="navItem" `id` is the `ID` they are referring to. You shouldn't have more than one ID with the same name. you could use class like : `class="navItem"` instead .. It would be better.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One reason might because you're missing a closing `</li>` in  `<li><a href="#" id="navItem"> Shop </a><li>`

```css
.nav{
  background-color:#660099;
  color:white; 
  height:20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding:0;

}

.nav a {
  display: block;
}
.nav li li{
  width: 70px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding-left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.nav li {
  width: 70px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 1px;
  text-align: center;

}
.nav li ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: inherit;
}

.nav li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
a{
  color:white;
}
```

```html
 <div class="nav" >
 <ul>
 <li><element>&#9917 </element> </li>
 <li><a href="#" id="navItem"> Home </a></li> 
 <li><a href="#" id="navItem"> Mail </a></li>
 <li><a href="#" id="navItem"> Team </a></li>  
 <li><a href="#" id="navItem"> Matches </a></li> 
 <li><a href="#" id="navItem"> Club </a></li>
 <li><a href="#" id="navItem"> Multimedia </a></li> 
 <li><a href="#" id="navItem"> Fans </a></li>
 <li><a href="#" id="navItem"> Shop </a></li> 
 <li><a href="#" id="navItem"> More </a>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Messenger</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Games</a></li> 
       <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>           
    </ul>
 </li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

I use `>`  in `.nav ul > li` to get the first level of `li`s in the ul with the parent `.nav`. If I used `.nav ul  li` it would get all the `lis` in the ul including the children that look like these: `<li><a href="#">Messenger</a></li>`. You just wanted the spaces on the top level of the menu that's why I used `>` . [about the >](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459821/css-selector-what-is-it)

**Better example that looks like more even spaces:**

```css
.nav{
  background-color:#660099;
  color:white; 
  height:20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding:0;

}

.nav a {
  /*display: block;*/
  text-align: center;
  color:white;
}
.nav li li{
  width: 70px;
  /*height: 30px;*/
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding-left: 0;
  /*text-align: left;*/
  /*margin-left: 10px;*/
}

.nav ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;

}
.nav li ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: inherit;
}

.nav li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
 <div class="nav" >
 <ul>
 <li><element>&#9917 </element> </li>
 <li><a href="#" id="navItem"> Home </a></li> 
 <li><a href="#" id="navItem"> Mail </a></li>
 <li><a href="#" id="navItem"> Team </a></li>  
 <li><a href="#" id="navItem"> Matches </a></li> 
 <li><a href="#" id="navItem"> Club </a></li>
 <li><a href="#" id="navItem"> Multimedia </a></li> 
 <li><a href="#" id="navItem"> Fans </a></li>
 <li><a href="#" id="navItem"> Shop </a></li> 
 <li><a href="#" id="navItem"> More </a>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Messenger</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Games</a></li> 
       <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>           
    </ul>
 </li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

You can also play around with the margin like:

```
  .nav ul > li {
      display: inline-block;
      float: left;
      margin-left: 20px;
      margin-right: 20px;

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove fixed `width: 70px` from `.nav li`. To achieve equal distance between the list items, you could use `margin-right: 16px;` for example.

Comment: Thank you, but how can you know how to apply in order to really work? I mean I've tried a lot of things for almost 2 hours and no results. How can I figure out how to use in order to work?

Answer (score 0):

watch out in the "HTML" you use "ID" and in the "CSS" you use "CLASS"

you can do it with flexbox

```css
.nav{
            background-color:#660099;
            color:white; 
            height:20px;
            margin-top: 10px;
    
          }
         
        .nav ul {
            list-style: none;
            text-align: center;
            padding:0;
            margin-top: 0px;
             display:flex;
      flex-direction:row;
      justify-content: space-around;

         }

        .nav a {
            display: block;
         }
        .nav li li{
            width: 70px;
            height: 30px;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 15px;
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            padding-left: 0;
            text-align: left;
            margin-left: 10px;
            }

        .nav li {
            margin-left:10px;
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;
            margin-left: 1px;
            text-align: center;

         }
         .nav li ul {
            position: absolute;
            display: none;
            width: inherit;
         }

         .nav li:hover ul {
            display: block;
         }
```

```html
<body style="background:#F0F0F0">
   <div class="nav" >
   <ul>
   <li class="test"><element>&#9917 </element> </li>
    
   <li><a href="#" class="navItem"> Home </a></li> 
   <li><a href="#" class="navItem"> Mail </a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="navItem"> Team </a></li>  
   <li><a href="#" class="navItem"> Matches </a></li> 
   <li><a href="#" class="navItem"> Club </a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="navItem"> Multimedia </a></li> 
   <li><a href="#" class="navItem"> Fans </a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="navItem"> Shop </a><li> 
   <li><a href="#" class="navItem"> More </a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Messenger</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Games</a></li> 
         <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>           
      </ul>
      </li>
     
   </ul>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you want all the list items the same width or the space between them to be the same...it's not the same thing.

**Space between**

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
}
.nav {
  background-color: #660099;
  color: white;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.nav a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: darkorange;
}
.nav li {
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body style="background:#F0F0F0">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>


      <li><a href="#" class="navItem"> Logo </a>
      </li>

      <li><a href="#" class="navItem"> Home </a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navItem"> Mail </a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navItem"> Team </a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navItem"> Matches </a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navItem"> Club </a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navItem"> Multimedia </a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navItem"> Fans </a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navItem"> Shop </a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navItem"> More </a> 
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

**All same size:**

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
}
.nav {
  background-color: #660099;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.nav a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  height: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: darkorange;
}
.nav li {
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<body style="background:#F0F0F0">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>


      <li><a href="#" class="navItem"> Logo </a>
      </li>

      <li><a href="#" class="navItem"> Home </a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navItem"> Mail </a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navItem"> Team </a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navItem"> Matches </a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navItem"> Club </a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navItem"> Multimedia </a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navItem"> Fans </a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navItem"> Shop </a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navItem"> More </a> 
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```