# CSS Selectors - difference between and when to use ">", "+" or " "

Tags: css, css-selectors

When using CSS, I can query elements in the following ways:

```
div > .class  
div .class 
div + .class
```

However I can't quite tell the exact difference between each of these `DOM` queries. Do they all point to child elements? I know that ">" and " " (space) do.

But under what circumstances would I use each?

Comment: [Immediate child, any child, and adjacent sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#Combinators)

Comment: [CSS '>' selector; what is it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459821/css-selector-what-is-it)

Comment: Have you searched something about those selectors ? .....

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In CSS these are called **Combinators** and means three different things:

1. `div > .class`:  is called [**Child selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) and will select all elements that are direct children of a `div` and have the class `.class`.
2. `div .class`: is called [**Descendant selectors**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors) and will select all elements inside a div and having the class `.class`.
3. `div + .class`: is called [**Adjacent sibling selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) and will match any element that immediately follows a `div` and have the class `.class`.

**Example:**

In the following example:

```
<div>
  <p class="test">
    <a href="#" class="test">
      Testing link</a>
    <img class="test"/>
  </p>
  <span class="test">A span</span>
</div>
<h4 class="test">A title</h4>
```

- `div > .test` will match only `<p>` and `<span>` elements.
- `div .test` will match `<p>`, `<a>`, `<img>` and `<span>` elements.
- `div + .test` will match only `<h4>` element because it follows the `<div>` immediately.

**Demo:**

```css
div .test {
  background: yellow;
}

div>.test {
  background: red;
}

div+.test {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="test">
    Pragraph
    <a href="#" class="test">
      link</a>
    <img class="test" width="50px" height="50px" />
  </p>
  <span class="test">Span</span>
</div>
<h4 class="test">Title</h4>
```

Comment: It's better to let the code explain what the answer is, and you did the same. 