# CSS: Target the first object of each class

Tags: html, css

I have a list of tags with 2 possible classes: P1 and P2. I want to apply CSS to the first item of each class. It doesn't work neither in my project nor in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ob0y953n/1/.)

Why is that?

```css
.A>.B>.C>.P1:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.A>.B>.C>.P2:first-child {
  font-style: italic;
}

;
```

```html
<div class="A">
  <div class="B">
    <div class="C">
      <p class='P1'>
        "JAJA P1"
      </p>
      <p class='P1'>
        "JAJA P1"
      </p>
      <p class='P2'>
        "JAJA P2"
      </p>
      <p class='P2'>
        "JAJA P2"
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:first-child` is an element selector so you can't use it to select the first of each class - it is just for selecting the first child of a parent element.

Instead, you can try the following trick:

1. style all of the class with your first child style
2. remove that style from following siblings

```css
.C>.P1 {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.C>.P1~.P1 {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.C>.P2 {
  font-style: italic;
}

.C>.P2~.P2 {
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="A">
  <div class="B">
    <div class="C">
      <p class='P1'>
        "JAJA P1"
      </p>
      <p class='P1'>
        "JAJA P1"
      </p>
      <p class='P2'>
        "JAJA P2"
      </p>
      <p class='P2'>
        "JAJA P2"
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

`:first-child` means "The element is the first child element inside its parent element". It doesn't mean "The element is the first child element inside its parent element **that matches some other condition**".

While there is a `:first-of-type` pseudo-class, there is no `:first-of-class` pseudo-class. CSS doesn't directly support what you want to achieve.

You can get close, and it supports the particular properties you want to set, with the [general sibling combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators).

```
.p2 { font-style: italic; }
.p2 ~ .p2 { font-style: normal; }
```

You set *all* the matching elements to be italic and then set the subsequent ones to be not-italic.

Answer (score 0):

It's cause you use the `>` selector. It selects the immediate children

[CSS '>' selector; what is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459821/css-selector-what-is-it)

That will work as you want :

```
.A .P1:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.A .P2:first-child {
  font-style: italic;
};
```

Comment: That won't work. (a) There aren't `<P1>` or `<P2>` elements in HTML. (b) None of the `.P2` elements are the first child in their parent element.

Answer (score 0):

You can try simple method by selecting (odd) 
https://jsfiddle.net/ob0y953n/13/.

More can read about ":nth-child" [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/)

```css
 .A p:nth-child(odd) {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: grey; }
```

```html
<div class="A">
  <div class="B">
    <div class="C">
      <p class='P1'>
        "Selected"
      </p>
      <p class='P1'>
        "Not Selected"
      </p>
      <p class='P2'>
        "Selected"
      </p>
      <p class='P2'>
        "Not Selected"
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this  method can't selected .P2 and also first-child ,
':first-child' choise his father and then choise 'first-child'.
so your .P2:first-child  means .P2 his father and  his fater's 'first-child' it's P1 but it is not .P2 so unused.
you should change to other methods.