# How properly I refer to a <li> in the CSS should I use e.g. ul > li or just ul li

Tags: css, html-lists

I've learned that if I'm refering to a `<li>` within `<ul>` or `<ol>` in CSS i should use `ol > li` or `ul > li` but once i forgot put the sign between ol and li and I've found that is working anyway. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459821/css-selector-what-is-it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the ">" (greater-than sign) CSS selector mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-the-greater-than-sign-css-selector-mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not equivalent!
Imagine a structure like

```
<ul>
  <li id="A"> </li>
  <li id="B">
     <ol>
        <li id="C"> </li>
      </ol>
   </li>
</ul>
```

than
`ul li` means ALL `<li>` in this example A,B and C while  `ul > li` only means the direct childs of the `<ul>` so A and B but not C

Comment: Ok so if I understand correctly in your example: ul li will get ALL <li> within <ul> also from <ol> since <ol> is child of <ul> and in consequence all <li> from <ol> are also <ul> childs but ul > li will get only direct childs from <ul> and <ol> <li> wont be affected by the changes made in code like:    ul > li {font-size: 10px;}

Comment: Exactly that's why it's called CASCADE style script ;)

Comment: You're incorrect. `ul > li` will apply styling to each and every list item. all list items **must** be a child of a `<ol>` or `<ul>`

Comment: yes but > is used for DIRECT childs at least that's what I learned

Comment: There is no such thing as a "direct child". Something is either a child or not. There's a difference between a child and a descendant however. You are a child of your mother and father but you're not a child of your grandparents. However you are a descendant of all of them.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp
`element element  div p  Selects all <p> elements inside <div> elements  1
element>element  div > p  Selects all <p> elements where the parent is a <div> element`

There is a diferent between "beeing inside of a div" and "having a div as parent"

Comment: Anyway I think the OP undesrtood quite well what I mean by "direct" child .. sorry for that word than but it was the easiest way to make me understood ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it works, because it "Selects all **direct child** elements specified by “child” of elements specified by “parent”"

like

```html
<ul>
<li></li>
</ul>

but not
<ul>
<li>
   <ol>
      <li></li>
   </ol>
</li>
</ul>
```

when you use ul > li selector, it will get only one direct child li element on ex.2, if used ul li then you will get tow li elements - all child li elements of ul

Comment: So in 2nd example: It will get only one <li> element or all <li> elements that are childs of <ul> so it will het all <li> from <ul> and all <li> from <ol> since <ol> is also its child so in conesequence all <il> within <ol> are also its childs?

Comment: ul > li means direct child element, so in ex.2 it will get direct li element.
ul li withoud > sighn means all ull children elements through all hierarchy and it will get 2 li elements, yes, selond is ol-s direct child but it-s ul-s indirect child but child

Answer (score 0):

They're effectively equivalent since an `<li>` must be a child of either a `<ol>` or `<ul>`.

The [child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) combinator, `>`, just means that the element on the right side of the rule in `x > y` must be a child (not just a descendant) of the element on the left. Since with lists this must be the case, your rules are equivalent and either is fine to use. Note that in terms of [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors), that the combinator has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `ul li` it will take any `li` inside an `ul`... That means that if you have, per example this HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>
    <ol>
      <li>one again</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

it will be applied to both `li` inside the `ul` and the `ol`.

BUT, if you use `ul > li` it will be applied only to the first `li` in the example, because it is a direct child of `ul`.

Comment: You're also inserting a `<ol>` in your example which you should point out. If your inner list was a `<ul>` all the list items would be selected

Comment: Thank you guys it is clear for me now! :) I would accept both your answers but i can select only one :) Thank you all!

Comment: @j08691  So if I use ul li and within <ul> there will be another <ul> then ul li will affect <li> in both <ul>? But if I would have <ul> and within it <ul class="xyz"> then ul li also would affect both or if there is a class it should be pointed by class like ul.xyz > li or ul li would still affect both?

Comment: @Luke_Nuke You can test this pretty easily. Adding an class would make your rules more restrictive because they wouldn't be applied to lists that don't have the class