# Change php to can select the html in css

Tags: php, html, css

I have a php code that display all categories of my store, the only problem with this code is give me this structure: ul > li > ul > li. I want to be able to change in css for example the **Parent Category** to have the color **red** and **Child Category** to have the color **blue**.

I try to use something like:

```
.sidebar.sidebar-additional ul li:first-child {color: red;}
```

but is not okay, both texts **Parent Category** and **Child Category** have the same red color.

What I can do be able to select both texts separately?

```
function categoryLoop($id){
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $categories = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($id);
    if($categories->hasChildren()){
    echo '<ul>';
        $subcategories = explode(',', $categories->getChildren());
        foreach ($subcategories as $category) {
            $subcategory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category);
            echo '<li>';
            echo $subcategory->getName();
            echo "</li>";
            if($subcategory->hasChildren()){ categoryLoop($category); }
        }
    echo "</ul>";
    }
}
```

The html output is:

```
<ul>
    <li>Parent Category</li>
        <ul>
            <li>Child Category 1</li>
            <li>Child Category 2</li>
            <li>Child Category 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thank you

Comment: You need the **child combinator** selector `>` and apply it like so: `.sidebar.sidebar-additional > ul > li {color: red;}` *Want learn more? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors* See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459821/css-selector-what-is-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to get this done:

**1. CSS**

Style the parent as red and the children to blue.

```
.container > ul > li {
    color: blue;
}

.container > ul > li > ul > li {
    color: red;
}
```

**2. PHP**

Output the parent with some predefined class, and children also with a different class:

```
<?php

$output = "";
foreach($groups as $group){
    $output .= "<ul class='parent'>";  // <---- add class here
    foreach($parent as $key => $category){
        $children = get_children($key);
        $output .= "<li>" . $category . "</li>";
        if(count($children) > 0){
            $output .= "<ul class='child'>";   // <---- add class here
            foreach($children as $key2 => category2){
                $output .= "<li>" . $category2 . "</li>";        
            } 
            $output .= "</ul>";
        } 
    }
}
```

Then with CSS:

```
.parent {
    color: blue;
}

.child {
    color: red;
}
```

The code you provided should change like this:

```
function categoryLoop($id, $is_sub = false){
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $categories = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($id);
    if($categories->hasChildren()){
    echo '<ul' . (($is_sub) ? ' class="category_children"' : '') . '>';
        $subcategories = explode(',', $categories->getChildren());
        foreach ($subcategories as $category) {
            $subcategory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category);
            echo '<li>';
            echo $subcategory->getName();
            echo "</li>";
            if($subcategory->hasChildren()){ categoryLoop($category, true); }
        }
    echo "</ul>";
    }
}
```

And then:

```
.sidebar.sidebar-additional ul li {
   color: blue;
}

.sidebar.sidebar-additional ul.category_children li {
   color: red;
}
```

Comment: It's just a pseudocode for you to understand the concept.

Comment: is not a good idea to use somethig like this in css ' ul li ' because there I have other ul li elements. So i need to do something to give separate names for both

Comment: As you can see, I added a .container class in my previous example. You should use something like that. As I don't see your DOM right now, I can't give you the exact solution.

Comment: where is the .container class?

Comment: `.sidebar.sidebar-additional` is your container class.

Comment: all things have the same color, red color

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the recursivity there. Wait. I'll update this.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set all `li` to red, and then target the `li` you want to be blue, by specifically selecting those that are nested within two `ul`

```css
ul li {
  color: red;
}

ul ul li {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Parent Category
    <ul>
      <li>Child Category 1</li>
      <li>Child Category 2</li>
      <li>Child Category 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the direct child selector `ul > li` which selects only the direct child and not the lower childs

```
ul > li {
    /*the first level*/
}
ul > li > ul > li{
    /*the second level*/
}
```

Alternatively:

```
function categoryLoop($id){
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$categories = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($id);
if($categories->hasChildren()){
echo '<ul class="second_level">';
    $subcategories = explode(',', $categories->getChildren());
    foreach ($subcategories as $category) {
        $subcategory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category);
        echo '<li>';
        echo $subcategory->getName();
        echo "</li>";
        if($subcategory->hasChildren()){ categoryLoop($category); }
    }
echo "</ul>";
}
```

}

**CSS**

```
ul > li {color: red}
ul.second_level > li {color: blue}
```

Comment: I try like this is not work, I don't know the reason. but even like this, how I can add a class in the css to can separate the things?

Comment: but can you put there how will be my php with something like this?

Comment: your php only prints the classes you need (as I wrote), or maybe I'm not undestanding what you need...

Comment: I edited my answer... you select the first level without a class and a second with the class of child ul

Comment: like all elements now have the red color

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156913/discussion-between-daniele-fois-and-robert).