# CSS Selecting all elements with a class inside a <body> with a class

Tags: css

I'm using a CMS(Joomla), and they allow me to put a class for a  tag and then I can modify the css for just that particular page.

I'm trying to use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors) to find the answer but I couldn't exactly get it to work the way I wanted.

Here is the JSFiddle they had on their page, I was messing around with it:
https://jsfiddle.net/amvz5dkb/13/

```
<div class="divclass">
  <span class="spanclass">Span #1, in the div.
    <span="betterspanclass">Span #2, in the span that's in the div.</span>
        <span="betterspanclass">Span #3, in the span 1.</span>
  </span>
</div>
<span>Span #4, not in the div at all.</span>
```

And here is my CSS

```
.divclass >  .betterspanclass {
  background-color: red;
}
```

This doesn't work, only

```
.divclass > span {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Seems to have an effect but it doesn't affect span 3 at all, only span 1 and span 2. I want to make the background red for every betterspanclass inside divclass. Is this possible?

Comment: Something lithe this ? https://jsfiddle.net/amvz5dkb/14/

Comment: It's because you are using the *direct descendant* selector `>` - Remove that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459821/css-selector-what-is-it The `>` selects the immediate children of the parent class ... so your code will only select the first child of `.divclass` -- if you want to select all of the specific classes, drop the `>` and go with something like `.divclass .betterspanclass` -- this will effect all the `.betterspanclass`es inside any `.divclass`