# navigation menu not going into display: inline block

Tags: html, css, sass, styles

i'm making an navigation menu that i want to position on the top right of my page. I want the items to be aligned horizontally, but i cant seem to get it working. This is driving me absolutely insane because i cant figure out what i'm doing wrong. I would really appreciate some help.

HTML:

```
<div v-if="items" class="main-nav">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li v-editable="item" :key="index" v-for="(item, index) in items" :class="{ highlighted: item.highlighted }">
                    <LinkType class="nav-link" :link="item.link" :linkText="item.name">{{ item.name }}</LinkType>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main-nav
        {
            width: auto;
            height: auto;

            position: absolute;

            top: 0;
            right: 0;

            float: right;

            transform: translateX(0%);

            background: #424242;

            > ul
            {

                > li
                {
                    display: inline-block;
                    .nav-link{

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: 1.  Please create a [mcve] demonstrating your problem (edit your question and press the snippet button to make runnable code from the rendered html and css that can demonstrate your issue).  2. Isn't working covers a lot of things.  Please explain what exactly is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**> selects immediate children** [Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459821/css-selector-what-is-it)

The right code will be

```
.main-nav
        {
            width: auto;
            height: auto;

            position: absolute;

            top: 0;
            right: 0;

            float: right;

            transform: translateX(0%);

            background: #424242;

           ul
            {

                > li
                {
                    display: inline-block;
                    .nav-link{

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Hence `ul` is not the immediate children of main-nav