# What is a triple greater than selector in css?

Tags: html, css, sass, selector, buefy

I saw the following CSS code with what appears to be a triple greater than selector.

```
.b-table >>> .table-wrapper {
  overflow-x: auto; 
}
```

I know it's referencing a Buefy table component and applying a specific style to elements that have a `table-wrapper` class, but what does the `>>>`operator mean exactly? Based off [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459821/css-selector-what-is-it) I'm thinking it might be for applying styles to children of children of children, is that accurate? If so, why doesn't it seem to work with other amounts of `>`?

Comment: This is not valid CSS. Are you using a preprocessor?

Comment: Interesting. I think the codebase is using Sass and PostCSS.

Comment: Are you using an older version of Angular? If so it's a deprecated equivalent to `::ng-deep`

Comment: @Chris W. No, it's using Vue.

Comment: Vue [uses it also](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`>>>` operator is Vue.js specific feature and called [**deep selector**](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#child-component-root-elements). In scoped CSS, you cannot apply CSS to child components without deep selector.

As your example, these two selector won't be applied.

```
<style scoped>
.table-wrapper {
  overflow-x: auto !important;  /* won't work */
}
.b-table .table-wrapper {
  overflow-x: auto !important;   /* won't work */
}
</style>
```

It needs deep selector.

```
<style scoped>
.b-table >>> .table-wrapper {
  overflow-x: auto; 
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is **shadow-piercing descendant combinator**. In Angular, `>>>`, `/deep/` and `::ng-deep` are the same (source: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep). It is deprecated and support has ben removed from major browsers. For example, it has been removed since Chrome version 63, around December 5 2017 (source: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6750456638341120)