# What does ">>>" selector mean when used in CSS styles?

Tags: css

What does `>>>` selector mean when used in CSS styles like in the examples below ?

```
<style lang="css" scoped>

.v-text-field >>> input {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-weight: 100;
}
.v-text-field >>> button {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
</style>
```

Comment: That combinator doesn't exist in CSS.

Comment: That's VueJS. Not normal CSS. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55801112/what-is-a-triple-greater-than-selector-in-css).