# What is option this ">" mean in CSS(html)?

Tags: html, css

I'm studying HTML using Codecademy.

I saw this code just right now, but I've never seen it before while I was studying

```
.color .swatch > div { flex-grow: 1; border-right: 10px solid #e6e6e6;}
```

What is the ">" option means? and What is that option name?

Comment: see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459821/css-selector-what-is-it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the ">" (greater-than sign) CSS selector mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-the-greater-than-sign-css-selector-mean)

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you. I understood it in more detail! XD

Answer (score 0):

It's the 'Child selector' (a lot more info: https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/)

It only selects elements which are immediate childs rather than anything under the parent.

Taken from the link above:

```
ul li { margin: 0 0 5px 0; }
ul > li { margin: 0 0 5px 0; }
```

The first will select any `li` under a `ul`, so this would include sub-lists. The second selects `li` which are direct children of a `ul`.

Comment: Child selector! I understand Thank you very much! :)